# JavaScript - Convert webm to mp4

Tags: javascript, mp4, webm

I have looked a bit around, but I couldn't find a proper library and everyone point at a different direction.

So my question is simple; is it possible to convert a media (webm) on a web page to mp4 and immediatly start the download ?

I'm making an extansion for firefox, but I have no idea how to do the conversion part.

Comment: You should explain what problems you had with the different directions you got. Otherwise you will most likely get that exact same information again.

Comment: E.g searching for `JavaScript webm to mp4` leads to https://github.com/muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js as one of the first results. So what was the particular problem using/adapting that code?

Comment: Well, can you figure it out how he manage to convert an already existing webm video to mp4 ? Because I couldn't find out. I have been through his exemple there : https://github.com/muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js/blob/master/webm-to-mp4.html

Comment: By reading a file into `videoBlob` and pass that to `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(videoBlob);` or by passing a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) directly to `fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer`. The converting works, but it will be slow because of the missing hardware acceleration.

Comment: And as I suspected, the first hints you got were the same you already know. If you want to have a useful answer then share your previous findings. And if you have a specific problem e.g. with ffmpeg.js then create a question where you explain what you tried (including your code) to get that to work, and what exact problem you are facing.

Comment: Will do that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend handling something as complicated as conversion by yourself, and instead would use something like https://cloudconvert.com/api as a background service, so your plugin will query that API upload/download, and output to the users browser.

Comment: Using a clients side api also has advantages. You don’t waste bandwidth, you don’t need to check how that service provider handles the data, you could use it even if that service provider is not reachable.

Comment: I am aware of that solution, but I rather don't want to be depend of it. Plus, you have to pay for API keys, wich is definitly a block on my project.

Comment: Understood! Just listing a possibility as you didn't specify. I've not investigated any  possible JS packages that handle conversion, but I'm curious!